# How do I fix my broken packages for 13.10

Tags: apt, package-management

I really need to install some updates onto my computer but every time it says:

```
The package system is broken

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
```

So I went into terminal and ran the command and it did absolutely nothing. I then tried `sudo apt-get update` and it also did absolutely nothing.

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual error into your question, it's impossible to determine how to fix it without seeing that output, thanks!

Comment: Also, are you using apt-get directly in the Terminal or Synaptic (or equivalent)?

Comment: Please post the exact commands you are running as well as the exact error message. Also please tell us what repositories and ppa you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Run the next commands on the terminal and cross your fingers:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update`

Comment: The first command will fail; there's a typo in "dpkg".